# Rails image upload with carrier wave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, upload, carrierwave, jquery-file-upload

I successfully created a form for User model where i can upload image with carrier wave. This works nicely with submit button.

Everything is fine but i want to improve that with jquery file upload or something similar. So my imagination is i will click on file_upload button then select the file and after that it will preview the thumb of image.

I tried to follow railcast #381 but when i upload image, the preview will appear after refresh of page. Is it better to use js response or json? Is there a better way for ajax image upload? Thanks for advices

Answer (score 0):

See the Attached [image]: Then use the following code.

Clicking on the "Upload different file" will trigger the **hidden** file uploader.

```
$('#page3-upload-bg-picture-link').click(function(){
    $("#page3-upload-bg-picture").trigger("click");
});
```

Then if you upload a file, it will call the `change` funcution.

```
$("#page3-upload-bg-picture").change(function(){
    page3BgImage(this);
});
```

Then the `page3BgImage` is going to be called. Here, the image is read from the location and show in my image's "You Uploaded Image" div.

```
function page3BgImage(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#page3-preview-bg-image').attr('src', e.target.result);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
```